# preventing multiple simultaneous queries with php/mysql live search

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, search

I have a working live search system that on the whole works very well. However it often runs into the problem that many versions of the search query on the server are running simultaneously, if users are typing faster than the results can be returned.

I am aborting the ajax request on receoipt of a new one, but that of course does not affect the query already in process on the server, and you end up with a severe bottleneck and a long wait to get your final results. I am using MySQL with MyISAM tables for this, and there does not seem to be any advantage in converting to InnoDB as the result sets will be the sane rows.

I tried using a session variable to make php wait if this session already has a query in progress but that seems to stop it working altogether.

The problem is solved if I make the ajax requests syncrhonous, but that would rather defeat the object here.

I was wondering if anyone had any suggestions as to how to make this work properly.

Best regards
John

Answer (score 2):

Before doing anything more complicated, have you considered not sending the request until the user has stopped typing for at least a certain time interval (say, 1 second)? That should dramatically cut the number of requests being made with little effort on your part.

Comment: This is the answer you're looking for. Setup a simple timer that executes your request after reaching 1 second. Then have the timer reset with each key press so it'll only fire after x seconds of inactivity.

Comment: I'm guessing the user needs to press "enter" before the ajax request is sent.

Comment: @ace That's not always desirable. Imagine a CRM-type app that autocompletes company names in a certain form, and you want it to answer as early in the data entry process as possible without requiring special actions from the user (like pressing "enter"). Still, you don't want it to fire off a new request after every single keypress.

Comment: Yes, I agree with CRMs but usually that's for data that's already loaded in the browser like countries, postal codes which don't need to be queried. I'm assuming it doesn't fire after each keypress as that's so heavy on the database. Especially when it starts searching after you just pressed a few letters, and paused a bit to think if it will provide you the best results.

Comment: It's hard to tell, but "AJAX" + "live search" + not wanting synchronous requests makes me think he's doing something like Google's live search where visitors see query results as they're typing and without waiting for them to press "enter" to submit the form.