# Save queries from AJAX autosuggest search

Tags: ajax, search

I want to save search queries from an AJAX autosuggest search textbox. When the user types in a character the search results are immediately shown.

The problem is to decide when a string is considered to be a query. When searching for "Lemon" it's not desirable to log L, Le, Lem, Lemo, Lemon. In this case only Lemon should be saved.

Also, sometimes a misspelled word is also of interest. "Lemmon" would be desirable to save since it would give the website owner valuable feedback about search queries that result in no items, when the user probably was expecting some.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'll implement a timer, as described in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6946353/preventing-multiple-simultaneous-queries-with-php-mysql-live-search

Answer (score 0):

You cannot programmatically decide, when it is a query, but the user can. You have to take the user-actions and save when he consideres it a real query.

For example:

- You display some autosuggest, and the user clicks on it. Now you only save this click as his search query (and maybe what he wrote into the searchbox)
- When the user submits the form, you save his query as a "Searchable World" and compare it to your autosuggest list.
- You have a Database of useful words, and when he types in one of these, you save this (by a counter?)

You should combine the first 2 Solutions to get a quite intelligent Database, but then you'll get intelligent data!